# Export to Excel in datagridView is working only while debugging

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, export, export-to-excel

I have a datagridview in c# where i am showing records.Now as per my requirement i have to export this into excel.So i have written following method for this..

```
    public static void ExportToExcel(DataGridView dgView)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        try
        {
            // instantiating the excel application class
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook currentWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)currentWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
            currentWorksheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 18;
            if (dgView.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
                int i = 1;
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn dgviewColumn in dgView.Columns)
                {
                    // Excel work sheet indexing starts with 1
                    currentWorksheet.Cells[2, i] = dgviewColumn.Name;
                    ++i;
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range headerColumnRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A2", "G2");
                headerColumnRange.Font.Bold = true;
                headerColumnRange.Font.Color = 0xFF0000;
                //headerColumnRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                int rowIndex = 0;
                for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgView.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dgRow = dgView.Rows[rowIndex];
                    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < dgRow.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                    {
                        currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1] = dgRow.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
                    }
                }
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fullTextRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "G" + (rowIndex + 1).ToString());
                fullTextRange.WrapText = true;
                fullTextRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            }
            else
            {
                string timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
                timeStamp = timeStamp.Replace(':', '-');
                timeStamp = timeStamp.Replace("T", "__");
                currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = timeStamp;
                currentWorksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "No error occured";
            }
            using (SaveFileDialog exportSaveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                exportSaveFileDialog.Title = "Select Excel File";
                exportSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Microsoft Office Excel Workbook(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

                if (DialogResult.OK == exportSaveFileDialog.ShowDialog())
                {
                    string fullFileName = exportSaveFileDialog.FileName;

                    currentWorkbook.SaveAs(fullFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, misValue, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, misValue, misValue, misValue);
                    currentWorkbook.Saved = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Exported successfully", "Exported to Excel", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (excelApp != null)
            {
                excelApp.Quit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Now one strange thing is happening when i am trying to get the excel report using my application i am not able to get that whereas if i am trying to get it by debugging my code i am getting but it too is taking hell lot of time.
On debugging the code This line ..

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range fullTextRange = currentWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "G" + (rowIndex + 1).ToString());
```

is taking considerable lot of time ..

Please help me ..

Comment: What is the size of excel file?

Comment: @LIUFA Its of 40 kb ..Is there any problem in my code ...?

Comment: Each time you update a cell, an RPC call will be marshalled to the Excel process. But you are using `Range` and it is already massive optimisation.

Comment: @LIUFA Can i get a short example or sample coding snippet for the same ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Excel Interop` is never going to be fast as you're remote controlling an instance of the Excel application. You might want to create a CSV file and then using `Excel Interop` to convert this to a `.xls` or `.xlsx` file.

Here's example on how to convert csv to xls

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

Excel.Application excel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workBook = excel.Workbooks.Add();

var inputFile = new FileInfo("Book1.csv"); 
var sheet = Spreadsheet.Read(inputFile);

workBook.ActiveSheet = sheet; // unsure about this part, but basically you need to transfer data.

workBook.SaveAs(@"C:\Temp\fromCsv.xls");
workBook.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the below section slows down your code a lot

```
int rowIndex = 0;
for (rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < dgView.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dgRow = dgView.Rows[rowIndex];
    for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < dgRow.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
    {
        currentWorksheet.Cells[rowIndex + 3, cellIndex + 1] = dgRow.Cells[cellIndex].Value;
     }
 }
```

I think it would be much faster to export `DataGridView` to an Excel spreadsheet by **not** looping through calling `Cells` each time because each call to `Cells` is quite expensive when using COM.

I suggest your convert your `DataGridViewColumn` to a 2D array and then export the entire `DataGridView` in one go like this:

```
object[,] toExport = new object[dgView.Rows.Count, dgView.Columns.Count]; 

for (int row = 0; row < dgView.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dgRow = dgView.Rows[row];
    for (int column= 0; column < dgRow.Cells.Count; column++)
    {
        toExport[row, column] = dgRow.Cells[row].Value;
    }
}

// export in one go instead of looping and accessing Cells each time
// use Excel.Application.Transpose(array) if needed
ws.get_Range("A3").set_Value(Type.Missing, toExport);
```

Additionally you may add an `xlApp.ScreenUpdating = false;` at the start and then switch it back to `true` when you're done modifying sheet.